# Is it correct from a function's perspective to say "a piece of diamond"?

Tags: uncountable-nouns, quantifiers

I'm designing a test for EFL students, basic level, and one item that refers to uncountable nouns was the following: "When I travel, I only take a piece of _______ for my security." My distractor was "diamond" 
—Thanks in advance for your answers.

Comment: Apart from the terminology, isn't a "piece of diamond" countable? I take one, two, or three pieces of diamond.

Comment: "A piece of diamond is incorrect." It is not impossible for "diamond" to be uncountable but it does not fit the context in the example. (Another thing: The question is very strange - there appear to be two errors in it if I assume that the correct answer is "jewellery.".

Comment: "Piece" is not idiomatic for diamonds.  "Fragment" or "shard" would be more appropriate, if I understand the intent.

Comment: What is meant to go in the blank? I'm having difficulty finding a word that fits and that is not awkward. Luggage? Identification? Artillery?

Comment: "When I travel, I only take one piece of jewellery for my security." is perhaps intended to be "When I travel, I only ever risk taking one piece of jewellery in case I am robbed." // 'a piece of ruby, opal, emerald ...' would be a sample taken straight from the matrix rock, perhaps cleaned up a little. 'a piece of diamond' would rarely if ever be used; always 'a raw diamond'. Perhaps you intended 'a single piece of diamond jewellery'?

Comment: A *piece of diamond* is like a piece of coal or a piece of graphite. It refers to a small object made of a specific material. This isn’t a common expression, but there’s nothing wrong with it grammatically.

Comment: Thank you everyone. It's very kind of you! For those who asked about the correct answer, it's "jewelry", of course. So, this is precisely the type of collocation that I intended to assess regarding the use of quantifiers with non-count nouns. Keep in mind that it's for a level one exam, so again, there are various types of limitations that I have to be careful with. I'm aware that "for my security" doesn't sound natural —"for my own safety" would do, but maybe I'll come up with something else. I also tried Google Books Ngram Viewer, this was the result: http://bit.ly/2wzDNCI    —Thank you!